# How to skip one instance in the dataset?

Tags: java, dataset

I have data set, when I partition it into training and testing , the training data contains one extra instance that has the value "NaN". SO i want to remove this instance from the training data, but I could not. 
Here is the code that was used and  a sample from the data

```
[{[2,-2,-2,-2,0,-2,0];1},
 {[2,-2,-2,2,-2,2,0];2},
 {[2,-2,2,2,2,-2,0];1},
 {[NAN,NAN,NAN,NAN,NAN,NAN];class},
 {[2,-2,0,0,0,2,0];2}, 
 {[2,-2,-2,2,-2,2,0];2}]
```

so far I try with the following code

```
Dataset[] folds = data.folds((10), new Random(100));
    Dataset training = new DefaultDataset();
    Dataset testing = new DefaultDataset();
    int[] tr = {0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9};
    int[] te = {1, 4, 7};   
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        training.addAll(folds[tr[i]]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        testing.addAll(folds[te[i]]);
    }

    int numFolds = 10;
    Dataset[] foldsTrain = training.folds(numFolds, new Random(1));

for (int i =0; i < training.noAttributes()- 1 ; ++i) {
    //Instance inst = training.get(i);
    if (training.instance(i).equals("isNaN")) {
        training.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Thanks, all

Comment: Are these your own classes? If so, why don't you check that all points are proper numbers?

Comment: Thanks @M.prokhorov. I do not understand what you mean but just to explain u that the NaN are come after dividing the data to train and test. That why I put this piece of code related to partition the data. The original data does not have NaN

Comment: I, from my part doesn't understand what does this code have to do with your question. Does `Dataset training` var contain strings or numbers? Why do you check for `"isNaN"` before removing when the value is `"NaN"`?

Comment: yes the dataset contain strings  and i check for NaN to remove the string that holds the NaN, because only one string has the value of NaN. Actually, I am worry about the result of my classifier that may affected by the value of NaN

Comment: You don't check for "NaN". you check for "isNaN".